# Radiative transfer in a two dimensional slab

Tags: fluid-dynamics, photons

I am trying to implement some radiative transfer to a hydrodynamics code. However, all texts that deal with multidimensional radiative transfer assume spherical coordinates, however the hydro code is a 2d cartesian coordinate code, in other words, I am modelling a rectangular slab.

My problem is in the source term. The hidro code has certain nuclear/particle physics reactions that generate N photons per reaction where each photon has energy E. However the photons are generated isotropically. What I can't figure out is "how many" photons are "injected" in the x and y directions, in other words, what is the x component of the radiative energy flux (Fx) and the y component (Fy) generated if the nuclear physics reaction generates isotropic photons?

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific about your radiation scheme. Is this ray tracing? Short characteristics? Flux-limited diffusion? A higher-order moment closure scheme? Elliptic solves to find the radiative transfer function?

Comment: I am not too familiar with radiative heat transfer but are you sure the energy flux has direction? Usually energy is a scalar quantity.